# QCheckBox, QRadioButton and QComboBox in QWizard: Signals/ Slots and SignalMapping - Information required

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qcombobox, qcheckbox, qradiobutton

I am trying to create a QWizard. I need to use combinations of QRadioButton and QComboBox in first Window, and QCheckBox and QComboBox in second Window.

In the first Window, the information coming as text per RadioButton is from Directories in a path specified, and the ComboBox list is the iteration of Directories inside RadioButton's directory.

In the Second Window, the process is same as above, instead of Radio buttons, there will be Check boxes though from another Directory path.

The radio buttons and Combobox are inter-dependent with Signals and Slots, if one radio button is checked, its corresponding Combobox must be activated and if next radio is chosen, the first must be disabled. But this is not happening, Combobox list is incrementing each and every time when I check it and corresponding combobox is also not disabling.

Here is my code:

```
    void SelectOption::initializeUi()
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Window-1");

    QGridLayout *gridLayout1 = new QGridLayout();
    gridLayout1->setMargin(5);
    gridLayout1->setSpacing(5);

    QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        radioButton[i] = new QRadioButton();
        radioButton[i]->setText(softwareList[i]);
        signalMapper->setMapping(radioButton[i], i);
        gridLayout1->addWidget(radioButton[i], i/1, i%1);
        connect(radioButton[i], SIGNAL(clicked()),signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    }

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const int &)),this, SIGNAL(radioChecked(const int &)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(radioChecked(const int &)),this, SLOT(test(const int)));

    QGridLayout *gridLayout2 = new QGridLayout();
    gridLayout2->setMargin(5);
    gridLayout2->setSpacing(5);

    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
        comboBox[j] = new QComboBox();
        comboBox[j]->setDisabled(true);
        gridLayout2->addWidget(comboBox[j], j/1, j%1);
    }

    QPushButton *nextButton = new QPushButton("Next >");
    nextButton->setDefault(true);
    connect(nextButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showMainPage()));

    QPushButton *backButton = new QPushButton("< Back");
    backButton->setDefault(true);
    connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showSelectOS()));

    QPushButton *cancelButton = new QPushButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton->setDefault(true);
    connect(cancelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(cancel()));

    QHBoxLayout *hboxlayout;
    hboxlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    hboxlayout->addLayout(gridLayout1);
    hboxlayout->addLayout(gridLayout2);

    QHBoxLayout *layout;
    layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addStretch(10);
    layout->addWidget(nextButton);
    layout->addWidget(backButton);
    layout->addWidget(cancelButton);
    layout->addStretch(10);

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    mainLayout->addLayout(hboxlayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(layout);
    ui->centralwidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
}

void SelectOption::test(const int id) // REMEMBER
{
    if(radioButton[id]->isChecked()){
        comboBox[id]->setEnabled(true);
        comboBox[id]->addItem(" Select anyone ");
        QString path = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/list/" + radioButton[id]->text();

        QDir dir;
        dir.cd(path);
        dir.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

        QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
            QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
            comboBox[id]->addItem(fileInfo.fileName());
        }

    }else{
        comboBox[id]->clear();
        comboBox[id]->setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all your radio buttons to one `QButtonGroup`. Then checking one of them will uncheck all others.

**Update** (code example).

There is absolutely nothing difficult in using `QButtonGroup`. All you need is to add `QAbstractButton` inheritor to it with `void QButtonGroup::addButton ( QAbstractButton * button )` method, all other will be done automatically. Here is a simple code example, adding three radio buttons to a main window in it's constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(QMainWindow::centralWidget());

    QRadioButton *r1 = new QRadioButton("r1", this);
    QRadioButton *r2 = new QRadioButton("r2", this);
    QRadioButton *r3 = new QRadioButton("r3", this);

    layout->addWidget(r1);
    layout->addWidget(r2);
    layout->addWidget(r3);
    layout->addStretch();

    QButtonGroup *group = new QButtonGroup(this);
    group->addButton(r1);
    group->addButton(r2);
    group->addButton(r3);

    r1->setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but QButtonGroup is no longer available I guess? Instead I've to use QGroupBox ?? Can you plz show me it in my code...

Comment: `QButtonGroup` and `QGroupBox` are two very different things. Why do you think it's not available? Are you using Qt5? Here it is: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qbuttongroup.html

Comment: Thanks again, I am afraid I don't know the usage of QButtonGroup with QRadioButtons, could you please help me with the code??